# Laravel: query JSON column that has array of objects

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb, query-builder

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | json_col |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | [{"key_one":4,"key_two":{"value":1,"type":"static"}},{"key_one":27,"key_two":{"value":26,"type":"dynamic"}}] |
| 36 | [{"key_one":2,"key_two":{"value":33,"type":"static"}},{"key_one":9,"key_two":{"value":1,"type":"any"}}] |

```json
[
    {
        "id": 35,
        "json_col": [
            {
                "key_one": 4,
                "key_two": {
                    "value": 1,
                    "type": "static"
                }
            },
            {
                "key_one": 27,
                "key_two": {
                    "value": 26,
                    "type": "dynamic"
                }
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2023-02-13T16:54:13.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-13T16:54:13.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 36,
        "json_col": [
            {
                "key_one": 2,
                "key_two": {
                    "value": 33,
                    "type": "static"
                }
            },
            {
                "key_one": 9,
                "key_two": {
                    "value": 1,
                    "type": "any"
                }
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2023-02-13T16:54:56.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-13T16:54:56.000000Z"
    }
]
```

How to get the row `35` that has `key_two` with `value` = `1` and `type` = `static`, using the query builder or a raw query?

Comment: Take a look at JSON where clauses in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses)

Comment: @geertjanknapen I have experience using that builder and raw SQL queries, I'm just facing difficulty with an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [whereJsonContains](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses) with multi-dimentional array base on how you store them.

```
return Model::whereJsonContains('json_col', [ ['key_two' => [ 'value' => 1] ] ])
            ->whereJsonContains('json_col', [ ['key_two' => [ 'type' => 'static'] ] ])
            ->paginate(10); // or get()
```

just double check the sql output actually looks like your json format which should look something like

```
WHERE json_contains(`json_col`, '[{\"key_two\":{\"value\":1}}]')
AND json_contains(`json_col`, '[{\"key_two\":{\"type\":\"static\"}}]')
```

**EDIT**

If you need to search multiple match in single object, then this should do

```
return Model::whereJsonContains('json_col', [ ['key_two' => [ 'value' => 1, 'type' => 'static' ] ] ])
    ->paginate(10); // or get()
```

Comment: Good answer, but sorry my question lacked some precision (I edited it). I need `value=1 AND type='static'` on the same `key_two` object.

Comment: I edited, my answer, but again, just construct them the way they look in php array

Comment: I can even do `whereJsonContains('json_col', [['key_two' => ['type'=>'static'], 'key_one'=>4])`. thank you for the clear answer

Comment: you're missing square bracket `]` before `4` in your example, but yes its easy to perform query with json object in laravel, although it depends on how you store and fetch them, and it could sometimes a nightmare to perform `%LIKE%` searches